# Refference an existing data frame with a string argument passed into the function

Tags: python, string, function, pandas, dataframe

I have an existing set of data frames that I have imported earlier as show below

```
import pandas as pd
class command_dictionary(object):
    def __init__(self, file_location ='command_dictionary.xlsx'):
        xls = pd.ExcelFile(file_location)
        self.enum_beacon_mode = xls.parse('enum_beacon_mode', index_col=0, parse_cols=1, na_values=['NA'], has_index_name=True)
        self.enum_boot_source = xls.parse('enum_boot_source', index_col=0, parse_cols=1, na_values=['NA'], has_index_name=True)
```

Later in the code i want to call one of the initialized data frames.

```
def validate_command(df_name):
    print df_name #do stuff
    print enum_beacon_mode
```

How do I take the `df_name` string argument and use it to call an existing data frame.

Thank you in advance for everyone's help.

Comment: store the references in a dict or simply pass the name to the function

Comment: I am unable to pass the full df into the function, the df_name comes as a string input from user. Which part should I store in a dictionary, do you mean the list of data frames?

Comment: How are the dataframes created?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at my question. The Data Frames are created through an import as shown in the 'def __init__'. I do not want to re-import the data frame every time the function is called. I would prefer to keep using the same data frame created in the '__init__'.

Comment: Is there a way I can use something like self.df_name

Comment: So lots of instances are created? I don't see where the names come from

Comment: I have about a dozen data frames created in the __init__. Then i would like to use these data frames in a function. The function is called with data frame name as an argument. How do I call an existing data frame with a string argument that was passed into the function.

Comment: get the user to pass the name and use a class dict to store all the df's by name